# Using SATB arrangements with a SAB choir

Tags: voice, harmony, arranging

I do not have any tenors but I have lots of music arranged for four parts. Can I simply leave out the tenor parts? Will it adversely affect the music?

Comment: The answer to this question is "Yes it will."

Comment: Unless your choir is very small, there is no reason why it *has* to sing in 3 parts even if you don't have any tenor voices. Split the basses and/or altos as required. Transposing the original tenor part up or down an octave to match your singers may work - provided it doesn't go below the original bass part or above the original soprano! You can vary the octave transposition phrase-by-phrase if necessary, of course

Answer (score 8):

You certainly don't want to just leave out one of the parts; it will almost certainly have at least *some* vital musical information that will hurt the final product.

Typically with arranging for three voices, you want to make sure you have a bass line, the melody, and enough harmonic support in the inner voices to fill out the texture. This means that every chord should have a chordal third, but that chordal fifths can be omitted. If you just leave out the tenor line, there will probably be several instances where the chordal thirds are omitted and negatively effect the music.

With only three voices, your soprano and bass lines will basically have to be the same; this means that one possible solution is to have your altos jump between the original alto and tenor parts to fill in the texture, but this will probably be an ugly (and unmusical) solution.

A better idea might be to get some altos and basses to form a tenor section and sing the tenor part. Or, occasionally have some altos split to sing the higher tenor parts while some basses split to sing the lower tenor parts.

Or, admittedly the best solution: find at least two tenors! (I know you probably can't...)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to split your men into tenors and basses anyway, and transpose pieces down. How far to transpose -- and indeed whether this is feasible at all -- will have to be decided separately for each piece. How high your men can sing and the tenor part goes will determine how far you *must* transpose down. Transposing too far down will make things harder for the altos, of course: how low they can sing and the alto part goes will limit how far you *can* transpose down.

Answer (score 0):

With any luck your choir contains some ladies with a strong lower range.  Designate them as tenors.  With their support, maybe you can persuade a man or two to attempt the tenor part as well.

Otherwise, is the choir accompanied?  A resourceful pianist can often cover a missing part effectively.

Or re-arrange the music.  Sometimes this will be feasible.

Or sing it yourself.